# summarize consecutive lines containing identical values in a specific field using sed (or awk)?

Tags: awk, sed

So far I've been able to get around *sed's* more advanced features like look-ahead/look-behind across multiple lines but I'd like to understand how tasks like the following can be achieved with *sed* as I have the feeling that my approach of doing this e.g. within *python* is not necessary and can also be done within a filter pipeline on *cmd*.

a stripped example of the data coming in is like this:

```
1b41cf70 0
1cb8dd19 1
620f0b67 2
620f0b67 3
f35d35fe 4
3a6fb62a 5
620f0b67 6
620f0b67 7
620f0b67 8
b958a7ea 9
f35d35fe 10
f35d35fe 11
620f0b67 12
```

the first columns width is always identical (contains a shortened hash-value) and the second columns content is completely odered, numerical and without gaps (and therefore potentionally unnecessary besides providing orientation on lenghtier lists).

the desired output would be either like this (putting the index of the last consecutive occurance into an additional column):

```
1b41cf70 0
1cb8dd19 1
620f0b67 2 3
f35d35fe 4
3a6fb62a 5
620f0b67 6 8
b958a7ea 9
f35d35fe 10 11
620f0b67 12
```

or even better with aggregated numbers of repeating values (math expressions (adding) seem to be more easily done with *awk* but my skills with that are even worse, so this is just to illustrate what other outcomes would be desireable):

```
1b41cf70 0
1cb8dd19 1
620f0b67 2 +1
f35d35fe 4
3a6fb62a 5
620f0b67 6 +2
b958a7ea 9
f35d35fe 10 +1
620f0b67 12
```

I tried to follow several similar but yet different questions found across the SO-space but could not wrap my head around possibly simpler parts possibly leading to a solution like why `sed '$!N;/^\([^\ ]\+\)\ [0-9]\+\n\1\ /{P;d}' sampledata` will cut lines with indexes 3,7,11 but not 8.

My system has GNU sed version 4.8 and awk version 5.1.0 installed and I'd love to learn how I could use one of them to get this done. And no, this is not homework but lengthy lists of hashes with plenty of redundancy that need to be compacted and compared. ;)

Comment: please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and revert your last edit on your question then.

Answer (score 3):

Completely ignoring the original second column, we may use `uniq -c` to count the number of times a string occurs repeated on consecutive lines.

Taking the two-field output from `uniq -c`, we may create a third field whenever a string occurs repeated more than once (on the form `+x` where `x` is the number of times the field occurs, minus one). We then rearrange the two first fields and print.

```bsh
cut -d ' ' -f 1 file |
uniq -c |
awk '$1 > 1 { $3 = "+" $1 - 1 } { nr += $1; $1 = $2; $2 = nr - 1 - $3; print }'
```

The `nr` variable represents the line number in the original file.

Output given the data in the question:

```
1b41cf70 0
1cb8dd19 1
620f0b67 2 +1
f35d35fe 4
3a6fb62a 5
620f0b67 6 +2
b958a7ea 9
f35d35fe 10 +1
620f0b67 12
```

Comment: Thanks for this elegant approach which seems almost readable to me as an _awk_-noob. However, the results I'm getting with your commands do slightly differ to the output you wrote as the lines containing the _span-count_ (beginning with `+`) carry the upper instead of the lower line-number in `$2` in my case, namely `620f0b67 3 +1` instead of `620f0b67 2 +1`, `620f0b67 8 +2` instead of `620f0b67 6 +2` and `f35d35fe 11 +1` instead of `f35d35fe 10 +1`. any idea, how to fix this? my guess is that var `nr` needs to be adjusted in the first set of curly braces but left intact within the second?

Comment: @antiplex Sorry, at some point the code in the text and the result in the text started to diverge. I've fixed it now by subtracting `$3` from the value of `$2` in the code. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: while its said _`"the second columns content is completely odered, numerical and without gaps"`_ at least you need to know the first number value before. i, e, you need open the file and read the second column of the first line then adjust the codes accordingly. maybe that's not 0, it's start from 10, or -20 etc

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'function prnt() { print buf, preV; preK=$1; preV=""; buf=$0 }
preK!=$1             { prnt(); next } { preV=$2 }
END                  { prnt() }' infile
```

Output:

```
1b41cf70 0
1cb8dd19 1
620f0b67 2 3
f35d35fe 4
3a6fb62a 5
620f0b67 6 8
b958a7ea 9
f35d35fe 10 11
620f0b67 12
```

---

```
awk 'function prnt() { print buf, (c?"+"c:""); preK=$1; c=0; buf=$0 }
preK!=$1             { prnt(); next } { c++ }
END                  { prnt() }' infile
```

Output:

```
1b41cf70 0
1cb8dd19 1
620f0b67 2 +1
f35d35fe 4
3a6fb62a 5
620f0b67 6 +2
b958a7ea 9
f35d35fe 10 +1
620f0b67 12
```

Comment: sweet, now I have an idea on how to use variables as buffers in _awk_ and do some conditional branching! what I don't get how the counter is initialized (can one increment an empty string (`""`) in awk?) and what the `c:""` part in `(c?"+"c:"")` exactly does.

Comment: @antiplex in no such way we can say you want increment a _string_,it has no meaning for me at all. this `c?"+"c:""` is known  as ternary condition written as __condition?retun-this-if-true:return-this-if-false__, so it checks if variable `c` is not zero then it return character `+` followed by its value `"+"c`, else it returns `""` empty string, and then we `print` the result.

Comment: indeed, _incrementing a string_ is a nonsense term, sorry for being not precise here. what I meant is that I wonder where/how `c` is initialized and to what value. all related assignments I were able to identify were `c=""` (line1) and `c++` (line2) and I was wondering what magic drives awk to seemingly turn an empty string into an int. thanks for clarifying the _ternary condition_-syntax, I was kind of close I guess but missed the details.

Comment: @antiplex ahhh, that should be `c=0` while emptying variables like `c=""` awk do covert the value of that var to string but then when we do `c++` it converts to number. and by default variables value is empty string and will be 0 if anywhere it used as number and no initialization is required (at least for your question) and of course for some other conditions we better do it. if you look into my answer revision history I removed `NR==1` and left only `preK!=$1`, because you didn't have first column anywhere which it is 0 or empty otherwise for those lines condition `preK!=$1` will be false...

Comment: ... because `preK` has not initialized, so it will be empty string whenever if `$1` was empty, or wil be 0 when `$1` also was 0 (that is awk job to perform string or number comparison/conversion, but also we can force it to tell aak which to use), so then its followed block will not be run that's why I was used `NR==1` to ensure it will be run on first line and then so followed block will be executed and then variables will be initialized from first line info. now I changed that `c=""` to `c=0` to reduce beautiful girl (awk) job a bit for conversion :  ) thanks for heads up!

Answer (score 2):

You asked for `sed`. Here are 2 versions close to your own attempt but
using POSIX [ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04)
extended regular expressions. Both keep a maximum of 2 lines in the
pattern space.

```shell
sed -E '
    :Q
    $!N
    /^([^ ]+) ([0-9]+)( [0-9]+)?\n\1 ([0-9]+)$/{
        s//\1 \2 \4/
        bQ
    }
    P
    D
' -- file
```

where:

- unless on last line (`$!`) appends a newline and next line to current (`N`)
- the match expression `/…/` captures fields 1 and 2 as `\1` and `\2`,
  a possible last index as `\3`, and finally next line's index as `\4`
- if field 1 repeats on next line the entire pattern space is
  replaced with field 1 (hash), field 2 (first index) and last index,
  and branches to start of script -- the empty regex in the `s` command
  reapplies the last regex used (in `/…/`)
- otherwise prints and deletes first line (`P;D;`) and resumes loop

Output:

```
1b41cf70 0
1cb8dd19 1
620f0b67 2 3
f35d35fe 4
3a6fb62a 5
620f0b67 6 8
b958a7ea 9
f35d35fe 10 11
620f0b67 12
```

---

If instead:

```shell
/^([^ ]+) ([0-9]+)( ([+]+))?\n\1 [0-9]+$/{
    s//\1 \2 \4+/
```

output becomes:

```
1b41cf70 0
1cb8dd19 1
620f0b67 2 +
f35d35fe 4
3a6fb62a 5
620f0b67 6 ++
b958a7ea 9
f35d35fe 10 +
620f0b67 12
```

`sed` isn't keen on counting (but it can be done).

---

Lastly, a few comments on your `sed` script which uses
POSIX [BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03)s

- don't escape characters inside `[]`s except for the escape char., `]`, and possibly `-`
- in BRE `+` isn't a quantifier but a plain plus sign
- no need to escape the space character
- for portability use a semicolon before `}` ending a list of editing commands
- the `d` command deletes the entire pattern space not just up to
  the first newline

Answer (score 1):

The following will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 != prev {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        prt()
    }
    prev = $1
    beg  = $2
}
{ end = $2 }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    print prev, beg (beg == end ? "" : OFS "+" (end-beg))
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1b41cf70 0
1cb8dd19 1
620f0b67 2 +1
f35d35fe 4
3a6fb62a 5
620f0b67 6 +2
b958a7ea 9
f35d35fe 10 +1
620f0b67 12
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 != prev {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        prt()
    }
    prev = $1
    beg  = $2
}
{ end = $2 }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    print prev, beg (beg == end ? "" : OFS end)
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1b41cf70 0
1cb8dd19 1
620f0b67 2 3
f35d35fe 4
3a6fb62a 5
620f0b67 6 8
b958a7ea 9
f35d35fe 10 11
620f0b67 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick obfuscating multiline find-replace solution (this time in Perl)

```
perl -0pe 's/(\w+) (\d+)(\n\1 (\d+))+/$1 $2 $4/g' file
```

The correspondent (gnu)sed version could be...

```
sed -rz 's/(\w+) ([0-9]+)(\n\1 ([0-9]+))+/\1 \2 \4/g' file
```

For the "+" output, we have to do some extra calcution:

```
perl -0pe 's/(\w+) (\d+)(\v\1 (\d+))+/"$1 $2 +" . ($4-$2)/ge' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

`datamash` groups the first field with unique values of second field. And `awk` prints the desired output.

```
$ datamash -W -g 1 unique 2 <input | 
awk '{gsub(/,[0-9]{1,},|,/, " ")}1'
1b41cf70 0
1cb8dd19 1
620f0b67 2 3
f35d35fe 4
3a6fb62a 5
620f0b67 6 8
b958a7ea 9
f35d35fe 10 11
620f0b67 12
```

```
$ datamash -W -g 1 unique 2 <input | 
awk '{s=gsub(/,[0-9]{1,}/, ""); 
print (s) ? $1 OFS $2 OFS "+" s : $1 OFS $2}'
1b41cf70 0
1cb8dd19 1
620f0b67 2 +1
f35d35fe 4
3a6fb62a 5
620f0b67 6 +2
b958a7ea 9
f35d35fe 10 +1
620f0b67 12
```